# failure to send SMS to the users

Tags: php

This is how I'm going to use an API to send SMS messages out to my customers if the item has been completed ahead of schedule.

when I write a message "Test Test.com - We test just text message"

so that it only pops up and says "test" and it does not print the rest of the text.

```
$callApi = file_get_contents("http://www.smsit.dk/api/sendSms.php?apiKey=xxxxxxxxx&senderId=xxxxxxx&mobile=45$tlf&message=".$_POST["smsTekst"]);
```

the error is that it does not write the whole text, as I would imagine that it would.

Comment: Try to use `urlencode` http://uk1.php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) your data before putting it in the query string.

```
$txt = $_POST["smsTekst"];

$txt = urlencode($txt);

$url = "http://www.smsit.dk/api/sendSms.php?apiKey=xxxxxxxxx&senderId=xxxxxxx&mobile=45$tlf&message=" . $txt

$callApi = file_get_contents($url);
```

Also, you certainly want to validate that POST data before you use it.